# Scheduling a Cron job with Python and 'Unrecognised Day of Week' error

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to build a cron job scheduler in python that grabs a schedule from a database and creates the cron jobs in linux using the crontab library. but I can't figure out how to get past an "Unrecognised Day of Week:" error when trying to add the day of the week I want the cron to run when it's specified from an array. Any help on how I can do this using an array would be very helpful.

```
from crontab import CronTab
from datetime import datetime

cron=CronTab('pi')

#the below line simulates grabbing the data from the database
row={'starttime':'2:56:00','sun':1,'mon':1,'tue':0,'wed':0,'thu':1,'fri':0,'sat':1}

#convert the "starttime" into the hour and minute to use on the cron
d=datetime.strptime(row['starttime'],'%H:%M:%S')
hour=d.strftime('%H')
minute=d.strftime('%M')

#figure out what day of week I want the cron to run on
dow=[]
if(row['sun'] == 1):
    dow.append("Sun")   
if(row['mon'] == 1):
    dow.append("Mon")   
if(row['tue'] == 1):
    dow.append("Tue")
if(row['wed'] == 1):
    dow.append("Wed")
if(row['thu'] == 1):
    dow.append("Thu")
if(row['fri'] == 1):
    dow.append("Fri")
if(row['sat'] == 1):
    dow.append("Sat")

#create the job
job=cron.new(command='python /home/pi/Documents/blinktest.py', comment='Schedule')
job.minute.on(minute)
job.hour.on(hour)
job.dow.on(dow) #<- this is the line I get the "unrecognised day of week" error

#write the cron
cron.write()
```

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Unrecognised Day of Week: '['Sun', 'Mon', 'Thu', 'Sat']'
```

Comment: Instead of 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Thus', 'Sat' put 'sun', 'mon', 'thus' and 'sat'....All in lower case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that still doesn't work. I know the strings are correct with capital letters because if I change the line that is giving me the error to "job.dow.on('Mon','Tue')", it creates the cron job just fine. It's like the dow.on() command doesn't like arrays but the formatting looks just like an array.

Comment: it should be job.dow.on(*dow)    not the asterisk in front of 'dow' argument

Comment: Thank you! Adding the asterisk worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having the same problem, as user1438644 mentioned in the comments, changing the code from

```
job.dow.on(dow)
```

to

```
job.dow.on(*dow)
```

did the trick.